# AVAudioSession: how to set buffering time for audio and video

Tags: ios, avfoundation

I am trying to record voice while playing a background music in iOS, Swift.
Everything works well but I feel a small delay in the recorded audio.
I think it is because of the buffering time.

I tried to find a solution to reduce the buffering time as much as possible.

[Configuring Device Hardware](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/OptimizingForDeviceHardware/OptimizingForDeviceHardware.html)

```
        // Set Audio latency
    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    do {
       try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord, mode: AVAudioSessionModeDefault, options: .mixWithOthers)
    } catch {
        print("Failed to set category!")
    }

    do {
       try audioSession.setPreferredSampleRate(44_100)
    } catch {
       print("Failed to set sample rate!")
    }

    do {
        try? audioSession.setPreferredIOBufferDuration(0.005)
    } catch {
        print("Failed to set latency")
    }

    do {
        try audioSession.setActive(true)
    } catch {
        print("Failed to set Active!")
    }
```

I don't want to degrade the performance of Audio quality.
I am not sure if I have done the right thing to reduce the delay.
For example, `audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord, mode: AVAudioSessionModeDefault, options: .mixWithOthers)`